# Приведение C# datetime к ms sql datetime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Проект на ASP.net MVC, хочу привязать к полю текущую дату,реализую через контроллер, как можно привести datetime C# {dd.mm.yyyy} к формату ms sql datetime{yyyy-mm-dd} ?

Comment: Вы используете Entity Framework?

Comment: Да,модель создаётся на основе шаблона из бд.

Comment: Тогда вам не о чем беспокоиться, записывайте экземпляр DateTime как есть

Comment: эм, представление при попытки сохранить говорит о том что в поле введена не дата,вот в чём проблема :)

Comment: Так вам строка нужна? Тогда как-то [так](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Если используется доступ к базе через обьёкты, то можно сделать обработчик даты через гетер-сетер свойства:

```
public string dateorder { 
  get { return (_dateorder == DateTime.MinValue) ? "" : _dateorder.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy"); } 
  set { 
     _dateorder = (value == string.Empty) ? DateTime.MinValue : 
    DateTime.ParseExact(value, "dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); 
} }
```

Вместо ParseExact можно использовать TryParseExact (это было бы лучше). У меня просто вся форма обвёрнута в try-catch.

На счёт MSSQL - поля в формат yyyy-mm-dd СУБД конвертирует в случае только если тип данных кастится средствами MSSQL и формат даты у базы никто не менял, формат можно поменять средствами MSSQL на другой  https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms189491%28v=sql.120%29.aspx.
Поэтому настоятельно рекомендую передавать даты в формате DateTime, что сделает ваш код более переносимым и устойчивым. Для этого вам прийдётся всего лишь запись делать параметрическим способом, что я так же очень рекомендую делать.

Вариант 2. На языке mssql можно так же явно указать формат это так

```
 SELECT CONVERT(VarChar, GETDATE(), 104)
 SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '31.01.2016', 104)
```

Comment: в MS SQL еще есть засада с диапазоном допустимых значений. Шарповому DateTime полностью соответствует только DATETIME2, у остальных диапазоны порезаны с одной или обеих сторон, в документации есть точные границы. Нарывался уже на такое, пришлось заменить MinValue в проверке на зависимое от SqlType значение

Comment: Пожалуй надо тогда добавить что `_dateorder == DateTime.MinValue` всегда выполняется для  _dateorder-БД = null, потому что это дефолтное значение DateTime, т.е. `_dateorder == default(DateTime)` но остаётся загвоздка - нужно тогда немного модифицировать setter и возможно использовать `DateTime?` nullable тип. С приведенной в ответе записью пока что багов не ловил.

Comment: не, при преобразовании из форматов БД багов нет, там все корректно, а вот при передаче в параметры запроса или процедуры всплывают неожиданности. В этом собственно и засада, что про преобразование БД =>Clr можно не  думать, а Clr => БД - думать обязательно =)

Comment: Используйте `DateTime?`  и `null` вместо minvalue. А проверку на границы нужно или в сеттер или в клиентской части.